# Bash Script Requires Enter Before Any Input

Tags: bash

I've written a simple bash script, named ocropus:

```
#!/bin/bash
read filename path
...
```

And then i realized that I can't run it like this:

```
ocropus filename path
```

Instead, I need to run it like this:

```
ocropus
filename path
```

What can I do so I don't need to hit enter before my inputs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the arguments instead of reading input. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are in `$1`, `$2`, etc. So do:

```
filename=$1
path=$2
```

instead of

```
read filename path
```